# Stress pattern of "trust me"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Are the words "Trust me" equally stressed? The vowel in the word "me" is a bit more tense (like in meet) I think. It's a two syllable phrase: [trʌst mi]

Comment: No. The emphasis would be on *trust* unless there were other candidates for that trust, in which case *me* would be stressed (as in "Trust *me*, not those other idiots.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pronouns rarely take stress in English, this phrase is likely to only have one stress. This will be on the word *trust*. The word *trust* will also be the nucleus of the intonational phrase. The word *me* will most likely occur in the tail, where it is likely to be said at a low pitch.

However, if the speaker is emphasising that you should trust them and not somebody else, then the word *me* is likely to have contrastive stress. In this situation *me* will become the nucleus of the sentence.

> Don't trust *him*. Trust *me*!

As the Original Poster included a phonemic  transcription of the phrase, it might be worth noting that the /t/ in this phrase is very likely to be subject to dealveolar elision here. In other words it is very likely to be dropped altogether. This would give us the transcription:

- /'trʌs mi/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't know about the dealveolar elision. I learned something new. Very helpful!